# Refresh(F5) logic of Internet Explorer

Tags: c#, windows, internet-explorer, browser

What is the programming logic used for refresh(F5) in IE. I want to implement the same logic in my C# application. Do anyone know the technical details of it. If so please share the same.

Thanx in advance

Comment: What is your application doing?  Loading web pages?  Refresh is no more than re-connecting to a server url and re-downloading the page.

Comment: Refresh == GET/POST + re-render the page... But it is unclear how it can apply to generic C# application. Can you clarify what your C# application is?

Comment: It's virtually the same as loading the page the first time. Is there some subtlety, such as caching behaviour, etc., that you are expecting to have to deal with?

Answer (score 2):

Process of F5, calls all the reload functions and functions are called again.

Please clearly specified about what find of application you are building so that i can tell you clearly.

Majorly in ASP.NET if you want to call F5, then simply reload the page by 
        `Response.Redirect(Request.Url.ToString());` for the current page.

Answer (score 0):

Refresh just request the page from server once again

To accomplish this Simply hit the url once again.

```
Response.Redirect(Url.ToString());
```

if using Webbrowser

```
WebBrowser.URL=Url.ToString();
```

if using Watin IE

```
ie.Refresh();
```

if you are facing cache problems , clear the cache and cookies and then refresh